# Find sum of roots

Tags: polynomials

Given the polynomial $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1=P(X)$. I know that $X^5=1$ and I need to find $x_1^{8}+x_2^{18}+x_3^{28}+x_4^{38}$ would this be equal to $4x^3$? What do I do next

Comment: Are $x_1, \ldots, x_4$ the roots of $P$?

Comment: yes they are the roots

Comment: Since you know the roots satisfy $x^5 = 1$, we have, for example, $x_1^8 = x_1^5 x_1^3 = x_1^3$.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2323526/a-polynomial-is-divisible-with-another-one/2323530#2323530

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_4$ be the roots of $P$. Then $x_i^5=1$ and $x_i=x_1^i$ for all $i$, hence
$$
x_1^{8}+x_2^{18}+x_3^{28}+x_4^{38}=\sum_{i=1}^4 x_i^{3}=\sum_{i=1}^4 x_1^{3i}=\sum_{i=1}^4 x_1^{i}=\sum_{i=1}^4 x_i=-1.
$$
(Here, we can "remove" the $3$ because $\{3i: i=1,\ldots,4\}\equiv \{1,\ldots,4\}\bmod{5}$.)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the last part,why do we remove the 3?

Comment: See the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Since
$x_k
=e^{2k\pi i/5}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
x_1^{8}+x_2^{18}+x_3^{28}+x_4^{38}
&=e^{8\cdot 2\pi i/5}+e^{18\cdot 4\pi i/5}+e^{28\cdot 6\pi i/5}+e^{38\cdot 8\pi i/5}\\
&=e^{16\pi i/5}+e^{72\pi i/5}+e^{168\pi i/5}+e^{304\pi i/5}\\
&=e^{6\pi i/5}+e^{2\pi i/5}+e^{8\pi i/5}+e^{4\pi i/5}\\
&=x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\\
&=\text{ the sum of the roots}\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$\prod_{k=1}^4 (x-x_k)
=x^4-x^3\sum_{k=1}^4 {x_k}+...
=x^4+x^3+...
$,
the sum of the roots is
$-1$.